# Cannot call stored, jit-compiled functions inside another jit-compiled function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

- Python 3.11.4
- numba 0.57.1

I am building a "compiler" class generating numba njit-ed functions from existing code

```
import numba
from typing import Callable

class Foo:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        
        self.compiled: dict[str, Callable] = dict()

        self.compile_bar()

    
    def compile_bar(self):

        @numba.njit
        def func1(a, b):
            return a * b

        @numba.njit
        def func2(a, b):
            return a / b

        l_c: list[Callable] = [func1, func2]

        @numba.njit
        def wrapper(a, b):
            for func in l_c:
                print(func(a, b))

        self.compiled.update({'bar': wrapper})

F = Foo()
print(F.compiled['bar'](1.,2.))
```

The last line throws an error

```
Exception has occurred: NumbaNotImplementedError X
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering)
<numba.core.base.OverloadSelector object at 0x7f996cd00c50>, (List(type(CPUDispatcher(<function Foo.compile_bar.<locals>.func1 at 0x7f996bcbcea0>)), True),)
During: lowering "$6load_deref.0 = freevar(l_c: [CPUDispatcher(<function Foo.compile_bar.<locals>.func1 at 0x7f996bcbcea0>), CPUDispatcher(<function Foo.compile_bar.<locals>.func2 at 0x7f99264c2de0>)])" at /workdir/porepy/scripts_vl/playground.py (33)
  File "/workdir/scripts/playground.py", line 40, in <module>
    print(F.compiled['bar'](1.,2.))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
numba.core.errors.NumbaNotImplementedError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: native lowering)
<numba.core.base.OverloadSelector object at 0x7f996cd00c50>, (List(type(CPUDispatcher(<function Foo.compile_bar.<locals>.func1 at 0x7f996bcbcea0>)), True),)
During: lowering "$6load_deref.0 = freevar(l_c: [CPUDispatcher(<function Foo.compile_bar.<locals>.func1 at 0x7f996bcbcea0>), CPUDispatcher(<function Foo.compile_bar.<locals>.func2 at 0x7f99264c2de0>)])" at /workdir/scripts/playground.py (33)
```

Now, `func1` and `func2` are only examples to keep the code compact. In general it is a list of njit-ed functions created based on some input args for `Foo`

I tried making a typed list

```
l_c = numba.typed.List.empty_list(numba.float64(numba.float64, numba.float64).as_type())
l_c.append(func1)
l_c.append(func2)
```

But the outcome did not change.

I think the problem is the access of the function via list indexing, because it happens only there.

Accessing functions which are not in a list seems to work fine.

The error message is quite cryptic to me.

Does anybody have a solution for this and an explanation?

Comment: Calling functions dynamically at all in numba jit code just isn't implemented I think. You might be able to use `literal_unroll` to fit your usecase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different problems: First, lists are generally considered to be hetegonoues, which doesn't play well with function pointers. Use a tuple instead: `l_c: tuple[Callable, ...] = (func1, func2)`

The second problem is that numba can't quite figure out the types of the functions before iterating over them. To fix that you can either provide an explicte siganture for at least one of the functions:

```
        @numba.njit("double(double, double)")
        def func1(a, b):
            return a * b
```

Or use `literal_unroll`:

```
        @numba.njit
        def wrapper(a, b):
            for func in literal_unroll(l_c):
                print(func(a, b))
```

All of these option producs a lot of warnings about first class function types being an experimental feature, however, in this case it seems to work. If you want to build the list of functions dynamically, you need to do that before the function is compiled. Just build it up as a list and then convert it to a tuple.

To silence the warnings, add `warnings.simplefilter("ignore", NumbaExperimentalFeatureWarning)` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Converting it to a tuple and assigning a signature to the functions did the trick.
`literal_unroll` gave an error though, but numba manages to iterate over the tuple.

Comment: @hajdukv Did you do literal_unroll and tuple? literal_unroll and list doesn't work.

Comment: I tried both, both does not work.
For the tuple it gave me an error that it cannot find a function to substitute getitem for tuples of those kind of callables.